Dotchart in R using ggplot2
i have a data frame in R called data that looks like this :
  Year  Color var value
1  2023   blue   A -0.06
2  2023   blue   A  0.04
3  2023   blue   G -0.27
4  2023   blue   D  0.05
5  2023   blue   L  0.18
6  2023   blue   B  0.28
7  2023   blue   B  0.15
8  2023   blue   E  0.10


i want to plot this data using dotchart in R using ggplot2 package.
doing so i did:
ggplot(data, aes(x = value, y = Year, color = Color)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +            
  facet_wrap(~ var) +              
  theme_minimal() +                 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

getting :

but i want to have each level of var column to be horizontally separated like this one :

How can i do it using ggplot2 and also and the vertical line to 0  across all categories ?
Also why ggplot2 reports 2021 while there are no 2021 data ? I want to drop it as well.
data
structure(list(Year = c(2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), Color = c("blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"red", "red", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", 
"purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"), var = c("A", 
"A", "G", "D", "L", "B", "B", "E", "E", "C", "A", "A", "G", "D", 
"L", "B", "B", "E", "E", "C", "A", "A", "G", "D", "B", "B", "E", 
"E", "C", "A", "A", "G", "D", "B", "B", "E", "E", "C"), value = c(-0.06, 
0.04, -0.27, 0.05, 0.18, 0.28, 0.15, 0.1, 0.02, -0.19, -0.04, 
0.22, -0.13, 0.05, 0.12, 0.19, 0.07, 0, -0.42, -0.05, -0.07, 
0.13, -0.23, 0.23, -0.09, -0.01, -0.11, 0.07, -0.23, -0.3, 0.15, 
-0.19, 0.09, -0.03, 0.03, 0, 0.11, -0.09)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))


facet with ncol=1, then use geom_vline at 0.

@zx8754 and the 2021 issue ?

regarding dropping levels: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031821/680068

To tell ggplot not to plot 2021, the Year variable needs to be "discrete" (aka a factor). You can then use facet_grid and geom_vline to get something close to your desired plot.
df |>
  mutate(Year=factor(Year)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = Year, color = Color)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  facet_grid(var~., scales="free") +
  labs(y="Year") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")



